# Pyinstaller not recognized

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was able to install pyinstaller and when I typed `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed frontend.py`
I got this error:

```
pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pyinstaller --onefile --windowed frontend.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment (conda, pipenv etc.)? if not - create and environment and the rerun your code

Answer (score 3):

`pyinstaller` should be in the PATH environment variable.

- First find the full path of `pyinstaller.exe` (It should be in the `Scripts` directory of your Python installation) and copy the full path.
- Then open a Command Prompt (As Administrator)
- Then run the Command `setx PATH "%PATH%;PYINSTALLER_PATH"`  where `PYINSTALLER_PATH` is the full path of pyinstaller you have copied.
- Then you need to re-launch Command Prompt and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

it means PyInstaller don't installed try :
[] - open Console/Shell/Terminal and write under command

pip install pyinstaller