# Pyinstaller Is Not Recognized

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I know this question has been asked before and I have researched and used the following steps to no avail, each one of them:

[Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

['pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435992/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

[Pyinstaller not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735474/pyinstaller-not-recognized)

I have installed and reinstalled Pyinstaller and have added it through the command line and manually to the PATH environment variable.

When I use pip show pyinstaller i get this as its path:

```
c:\users\globe\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
```

Edit: I am using Python 3.9.7, Windows 11, Pip list results in: pyinstaller 4.8 and pyisntaller-hooks-contib 2022

I installed pyinstaller via pycharm Python3 -m pip install pyinstaller and via the command prompt when that did not work

I am not sure what else to do as it has its location in the PATH and is certainly installed.

Any Advice?

Comment: When you run `pip list`, what pyinstaller entries show up? What version of Python are you using? It appears you're running this on Windows, what version? (just add the information to the question, instead of a comment). Also, you say you installed and reinstalled, but can you provide some information about how you installed it (using what tools, commands)? Are you installing into the global environment, or a virtual environment you created for this purpose, or project?

Comment: What is the output of the command:   pip help ?

Comment: It does look like your pip is pointing to a different python than what you think as it's 3.10, this could be some issue from using the windows store version (?). If all else fails you should be able to invoke it through `python -m PyInstaller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled multiple versions of python and reinstalled clicking the "Add to Python to PAth" option upon setup

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has the same Problem as Numerlor mentioned invoking it with `python -m PyInstaller` worked in a normal Terminal or Powershell

Answer (score 0):

1-check where is pyinstaller installed copy the path and add it to the system variable under Path->
**Note**: You Can See But Dont Copy Because it might be installed in different path on your system.
[You can See Steps ->](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gf0pSq4He-DwL_j-KhDkdqALHOIFxoyf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).